# Writing conditionals in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

I need to write a conditional in order to find users without facebook id's and then have a image path set for those users. Here is the code so far.

```
# load rails
    require '../../config/boot.rb' 
    require '../../config/application.rb'
    Rails.application.require_environment!

    users = User.order('id ASC').limit(500)

    users.each do |user|
        facebook_id = user.facebook_id

        unless facebook_id.blank?
            puts facebook_id.size
        end
    end
```

I was thinking maybe an if/then conditional so if the number is 0 (meaning blank) then input  https://graph.facebook.com/ + facebook_id + '/picture?width=120&height=120 for that user.

Maybe something like:

```
   if facebook_id.blank
        then input.('https://graph.facebook.com/' + facebook_id + '/picture?width=120&height=120')
```

Comment: Why don't you add a method on User that generates this path instead of saving it on the user?

Comment: How would I be able to do that?

Comment: define an instance method in your model that returns the image URL.

Comment: @Stevanity
How would I go about doing that?
`def poster_path(facebook_path)
   path = https://graph.facebook.com/' + facebook_id + '/picture?width=120&height=120
end`

Comment: if the facebook_id is blank, then make no sense to use it, so what you then want to do for these users? Because in above code, you try to use the not-existing facebook-id for them.

Answer (score 1):

For the query part this is the way to go:

```
User.where(facebook_id: nil) #=> returns all users without facebook_id
```

About the path, you were close:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base # reopen User class and define a new instance method
  def poster_path
    if self.facebook_id
      "https://graph.facebook.com/" + self.facebook_id + "/picture?width=120&height=120"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: self. is not needed there